# Drawing six cards from a deck of cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Six cards are drawn from a well-shuffled deck. You are told that at
>   least an ace (A) is among the cards. What is the probability that
>   there is at least a king (K) or at least a queen (Q)? (A deck consists
>   of 52 cards, with 13 values (A; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; J; Q;K)
>   each having 4 suits }

I took cases in the denominator (1 ace, 2 aces, 3 aces...) and tried to take the complement (there are no kings, or there are no queens).

Comment: Share your solution in more detail (together with the numbers you've found) so that we can guide you.

Comment: ... But please read the wiki for the [tag:self-study] tag first.  Then search our site for related questions, such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121953 or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113306, which might help you answer this question yourself.  Indeed, it turns out we have a rather large collection of (upvoted) posts concerning [drawing aces specifically!](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=card+ace+score%3A1)

Answer (score 0):

Let K: having at least a king

Q: having at least a queen

A: having at least an ace.

The probability of having at least a king or at least a queen given that there is at least an ace in the 6 cards drawn can be written as :

```
                          P(KUQ|A) = P(K|A) + P(Q|A) - P(K and Q | A)
```

We work to find P(A), and then use this relation for P(K|A):

```
                            P(K|A) = P(K and A) / P(A)
```

P(Q|A) is the same as P(K|A), and we use the same process and relations mentioned before to find P(K and Q|A).

Taking the complement was a big time-saver.